# How to return distinct result from "Update with Output clause" Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
UPDATE top (5) Alert SET Notify = 1 OUTPUT inserted.OrderNo as orderNo,inserted.UserId as userId 
  where UserId = ('rekon') and Notify = 0
```

Here is my update query with output clause, the records get updated for all the entries with the matching userId,  but is there a way i can restrict only distinct OrderNo's as a result of output clause?

```
UserId  OrderNo     Notify  ProcessedTime
rekon   3006856996     0             25:08.7
rekon   3006856996     0             12:05.9
rekon   3006856996     0             18:56.9
rekon   3006857268     0             12:27.0
rekon   3006857015     0             20:59.9
rekon   3006857015     0             14:08.8
rekon   3006856996     0             47:16.0
rekon   3006857015     0             27:11.3
rekon   3006857015     0             49:20.7
```

Comment: Why are there 9 output rows if your update uses `TOP 5`?  In any case, I couldn't find a way to do this, but there might be a workaround.

Comment: You can output into a temp table, or table valued parameter, and then select the distinct result from that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is the actual data not the output data, even in output there can be a duplicate OrderNo. In This case there will be only 5 outputs.

Comment: any one please mention the tag related to this type of `update` query. Because, I never seen query like `UPDATE top (5) Alert SET Notify = 1 OUTPUT inserted.table`. If you mention, I will study more about it.....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OUTPUT Clause is defined like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> ::=   {
>       [ OUTPUT  INTO { @table_variable | output_table } [ ( column_list ) ] ]
>       [ OUTPUT  ]   }    ::=   {  | scalar_expression } [ [AS] column_alias_identifier ]
>       [ ,...n ]
>
> ::=   { DELETED | INSERTED | from_table_name } . { * |
>   column_name }
>       | $action

So you can use it like this:

```
UPDATE TOP (5) Alert 
   SET Notify = 1 
OUTPUT inserted.OrderNo as orderNo,
       inserted.UserId as userId
 INTO #tmpNotify
WHERE UserId = ('rekon') 
  AND Notify = 0

-- then select it:
SELECT distinct orderNo,
                 userId
  FROM #tmpNotify
```